# How can i wrap every graph below in a bracket?

Tags: brackets

I have seen commands like `\bigg`, `\Bigg` and etc. But however I cannot apply them since im dealing with graphs which I manually put on the vertices and edges. I'm just new to latex, help will be highly appreciated :DD.
Here's a screenshot of my work:

[image: Enter image description]

Comment: Welcome! Please add a minimal working example (MWE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i assumed, that with "bracket" you mean curly braces. if this is not a case, please adequately replace used `\}`.

i also assume that your graphs are drawn with the `tikz` package. code for it is simple and it should be straightforward from given code in my answer to obtain desired image. in second equation line images are completed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
V/.style = {% Vertex
    circle, draw, semithick,
    inner sep=2pt,
    node contents={},
    node distance=6mm and 6mm,
            }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
P_{C_4}(k) = \left\{\tikz[baseline]{
                        \node (v1) [V];
                        \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
                        \node (v3) [V, below right=of v2];
                        \node (v4) [V, below  left=of v3];
                        \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v4) -- (v1);
                                    }
               \right\}
    & = \left\{\tikz[baseline]{
        \node (v1) [V];
        \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
        \node (v3) [V, below right=of v2];
        \node (v4) [V, below  left=of v3];
        \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v4) -- (v1);
                    }
\right\} +
    \left\{\tikz[baseline]{
        \node (v1) [V];
        \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
        \node (v3) [V, below right=of v2];
        \node (v4) [V, below  left=of v3];
        \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v4) -- (v1);
                    }
      \right\}  \\
    & = \left\{\tikz[baseline]{
        \node (v1) [V];
        \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
        \node (v3) [V, below right=of v2];
        \node (v4) [V, below  left=of v3];
        \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v4) -- (v1)
              (v2) -- (v4)    (v1) -- (v3);
                    }
 \middle\}
    + \middle\{\tikz[baseline]{
        \node (v1) [V];
        \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
        \node (v3) [V, below right=of v2];
        \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v1);
                    }
      \middle\}
    + \middle\{\tikz[baseline]{
            \node (v1) [V];
            \node (v2) [V, above right=of v1];
            \node (v3) [V, below right=of v1];
            \draw (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v1);
                        }
          \middle\}
            + \middle\{\tikz[baseline]{
            \node (v1) [V];
            \node (v2) [V, right=of v1];
            \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                        }
              \right\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```